# What happens to linked objects when you choose to pack external data

Tags: linked-data

I usually pack my textures into the .blend file via the "file"-->"external data"-->"pack all into .blend file" command.

This time my Blender project contains objects linked from other blender files and I'm uncertain of what happens if I choose to pack external data.

The question is basically this:
If I choose to pack external files, will changing the original Blender files any longer update the meshes in the blend file to which they have been brought to via linking? Or am I essentially severing the links if I pack the external data?

Answer (score 1):

No, at least in my test, nothing bad happens to the linked files. Linking still works and the textures get packed nicely.

For this kind of stuff it's fast and useful to just make test blends with cubes and spheres to toy around with in order to find out what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Here's the part that confuses me: I packed the external data and moved only the main blender-file to another computer. The objects are still there. Obviously Blender can't magically update the main file if I change the linked files on another computer, which still leads me to believe that the links get severed.